How to create a filtered view of a database inside a different DB page that matches the date of the relation page without manual input in Notion?
I have a page generated every day where its name is the date of the generation. I want to have a filtered task database within the generated page where any pages within the related database have the same date as the generated page will show up in that filter.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
